# Too many namespaces error

Tags: error, lead-conversion, namespace

Once in awhile when I try to convert a lead, I get the following error:

> Error: System.LimitException: Too many namespaces accessed: 10 External entry point

It happens pretty infrequently and I can't identify any commonalities with the records it happens to. I've run a debug log to try and identify the problem and it's occurring once it enters a managed package, but I'm not sure *what* inside the package is causing the error. It enters a few packages prior to the last one without problem.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to see a debug log with the individual triggers/classes firing to narrow it down a bit more?
2. Is there a way to see each namespace accessed within the debug log?
3. Is there any other good way of resolving this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For what it's worth I've heard stories that salesforce sometimes is willing to increase this limit with a good business justification.

Answer (score 9):

So, this is the [Maximum number of unique namespaces referenced](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_apex_governor_limits.htm) limit, which currently maxes out at 10.

The explanation from the linked documentation:

> In a single transaction, you can only reference 10 unique namespaces. For example, suppose you have an object that executes a class in a managed package when the object is updated. Then that class updates a second object, which in turn executes a different class in a different package. Even though the second package wasn’t accessed directly by the first, because it occurs in the same transaction, it’s included in the number of namespaces being accessed in a single transaction.

So, probably based on the triggers firing and subsequent DML operations, the code is reaching more than 10 different namespaces.

In the debug logs the first thing I'd look for would be `LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS` events. There will be one of these for each namespace, with the namespace identified in the first data after the event. E.g.

```
19:01:46.137 (1137952897)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|TheNamespaceHere|
```

The other useful events to look for will be:

- `CODE_UNIT_STARTED`. These occur when the triggers start. Again, the namespace is included in the subsequent data.
- `ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG`. Useful as it only requires the INFO log level. (Thanks for the comment Chris)

Resolving the problem will largely depend on how all the different packages are being reached. It may be necessary to make some of the processing asynchronous.

---

Try using something like the following from the Developer Console anonymous Apex to capture the debug log:

```
Lead testLead = [Select Id from Lead Limit 1];

Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(testLead.id);

LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

System.assert(false, 'rollback transaction');
```

Comment: I don't see either of those events in my logs. I've run the debug on FINE and FINEST -- are these the wrong levels to run the log at?

Comment: `LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS` "should" appear with the FINEST level on ApexProfiling. `CODE_UNIT_STARTED` should appear with ERROR on ApexCode. All other levels can be ERROR or NONE. Salesforce did fiddle with the logging levels a bit in Winter '16. Let me check.

Comment: I see `LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS` listed under ApexProfiling at the FINEST level, but I don't see `CODE_UNIT_STARTED` on any level for Apex Code. I double-checked and ran another log and still don't see either within the log. I'm running the debug on sandbox, would that affect it at all?

Comment: As far as I know LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS should appear in a sandbox log. Maybe try using anonymous apex from the developer console to capture the log.

Comment: Looking for ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG might be good, since it shows at INFO rather than FINEST it's less likely to get truncated.

Comment: @DanielBallinger using the anonymous apex to capture the log worked, so I can now see the `LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS` and `CODE_UNIT_STARTED` events. What I wound up doing was deactivating two triggers that were executing and responsible for all the `LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS` events and then re-executed your anonymous apex. The end result was another failure, this time the only `CODE_UNIT_STARTED` event was the anonymous apex itself and there were no `LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS` events -- any ideas why this would still fail?

Comment: @Matt Is it still failing with the same LimitException? Does the log end with a "MAXIMUM DEBUG LOG SIZE REACHED" message. If so, it will be missing details about what was occurring. You will need to adjust various logging levels to see the complete picture. Also, as Chris commented. look for the ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG events. I mostly see these in my developer edition org, but they may help in the sandbox/prod org as well.

Comment: @DanielBallinger it still fails with the same LimitException and it doesn't end with the max debug log size message. I looked at the `ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG` events and found 11 unique ones, with the process failing immediately after the 11th event. I assume this is the cause? Is there any way to rectify this without uninstalling packages?

Comment: @Matt That sounds like the cause. The question then becomes why are triggers from all those packages being accessed and do they need to be. You might need to deactivate certain triggers. It will really depend on what you need from each package. Lead conversion is probably a difficult one as it will include changes to both Leads and Contacts at a minimum.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. It seems to me that the conversion process should have a higher limit since there is a high likelihood that managed packages will have triggers on one of the many standard objects that can be involved in the conversion process, and in many cases removing managed packages won't be a viable solution. If you agree please vote for my idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cJH3AAM.